# Changing Control ID with Prefix 'ct100' in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

While checking my page control id is like - **ContentPlaceHolder1_lnkDistributors**.

But, After hosted my site in live server, Prefix is adding to above ID.

like: **ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lnkDistributors**.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDistributors" runat="server" Text="Distributors">
</asp:LinkButton>
```

Please help me.
Thanks in Adv.

Comment: What ASP.NET version ? And why do you need client ID ? To use it in a javascript ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Static ClientIDMode** is intended to control `ID` in HTML; but you have to use it carefully: it doesn't guarantee, instead, uniqueness of control ID in Page.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDistributors" ClientIDMode="Static"  
 runat="server" Text="Distributors">  </asp:LinkButton>
```

If your control has its ClientIDMode set to `AutoID`, the control's ID will have a prefix to make it unique. (e.g. A control with an ID of "sam" will become "ct100_sam").
If your control has its ClientIDMode set to `Static`, the ID will not be changed and stay as to what the developer has set it to.

---

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode.aspx)

ASP.NET provides multiple algorithms for how to generate the ClientID property value. You select which algorithm to use for a control by setting its ClientIDMode property. The algorithms are identified by the ClientIDMode enumeration values that are listed in the following list.

> ### AutoID
>
> The ClientID value is generated by concatenating the ID values of each parent naming container with the ID value of the
>   control. In data-binding scenarios where multiple instances of a
>   control are rendered, an incrementing value is inserted in front of
>   the control's ID value. Each segment is separated by an underscore
>   character (_). This algorithm was used in versions of ASP.NET earlier
>   than ASP.NET 4.
>
> ### Static
>
> The ClientID value is set to the value of the ID property. If the control is a naming container, the control is used as the top
>   of the hierarchy of naming containers for any controls that it
>   contains.
>
> ### Predictable
>
> This algorithm is used for controls that are in data-bound controls. The ClientID value is generated by concatenating
>   the ClientID value of the parent naming container with the ID value of
>   the control. If the control is a data-bound control that generates
>   multiple rows, the value of the data field specified in the
>   ClientIDRowSuffix property is added at the end. For the GridView
>   control, multiple data fields can be specified. If the
>   ClientIDRowSuffix property is blank, a sequential number is added at
>   the end instead of a data-field value. This number begins at zero and
>   is incremented by 1 for each row. Each segment is separated by an
>   underscore character (_).
>
> ### Inherit
>
> The control inherits the ClientIDMode setting of its NamingContainer control. The default value of ClientIDMode for a page
>   is Predictable. The default value of ClientIDMode for a control is
>   Inherit. Because the default for controls is Inherit, the default
>   generation mode is Predictable. (However, if you use Visual Studio to
>   convert a Web project to ASP.NET 4 from an earlier version, Visual
>   Studio automatically sets the site default to AutoID in the Web.config
>   file.)

Answer (score 1):

I have added `ClientIDMode="Static"` to master page.

```
<%@ Master  ClientIDMode="Static"....
```

Here ID will comes like: only **lnkDistributors**, not like ContentPlaceHolder1_lnkDistributors or ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lnkDistributors.

Now its working fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable auto incrementing the `Id` in an ASP.NET Application at either the page or the application level. For the page level, add the `ClientIDMode="Static"` in the `@master` directive. For the application level, add `ClientIDMode="Static"` to the `web.config`.